# Android Studio, how to use existing signing config after converting from legacy to kotlin gradle?

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I have a legacy project I'd like to convert to kotlin gradle in Android Studio. I'm less able to solve for this, as I don't actually understand how my legacy project is getting signed either. It feels like a bit of some type of magic keystore feature in Android Studio.

I can generate and sign a release app bundle with the below:
build.gradle

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
//            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

While I can see I have my signingConfig signingConfigs.debug mislabled as 'debug', it works well.

And, from **project structure dialog**, I can see 'debug' listed with a 'key' icon under Signing Configs

[image]

But, when I attempt to make a kotlin gradle file, I'm not sure how to refer to and use my keystore properly.

Do I need to declare a "signingConfigs" entry? or is there a magic one available like the legacy build.gradle is able to pick up?

What would go here in the release build section to simply do what I have in the legacy build.gradle as "signingConfig signingConfigs.debug" ?

Where are these signingConfigs managed?

```
    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            isDebuggable = true
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
//            signingConfig (signingConfigs.debug)
        }
        getByName("debug") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            isDebuggable = true
//            minifyEnabled (false)
            proguardFiles (getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }
```

I have this in my profile .android folder
[image]

I'm not certain at this time how the legacy build works, I don't find a reference to either debug.keystore or to maps.key, or 'signingConfigs' in the entire android studio project folder structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the android gradle plugin uses the `debug.keystore` found in your `$HOME/.android`, or generates one if it isn't there.

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#debug-mode

> When running or debugging your project from the IDE, Android Studio automatically signs your app with a debug certificate generated by the Android SDK tools. The first time you run or debug your project in Android Studio, the IDE automatically creates the debug keystore and certificate in $HOME/.android/debug.keystore, and sets the keystore and key passwords.

Note that this keystore has a default password and is not secure for use in release builds. You should create your own keystore and move to signing with that ASAP.